# I don’t really get the meaning of the last sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Strange_Death_of_Europe) I read

> The neuroscientist and philosopher Sam Harris lauded the book as "wonderful".[2] Writing in the National Review, Michael Brendan Dougherty praised it as "informed by actual reporting across the Continent, and a quality of writing that manages to be spritely and elegiac at the same time. Murray's is also a truly liberal intellect, in that he is free from the power that taboo exerts over the European problem, **but he doesn’t betray the slightest hint of atavism or meanspiritedness**

Comment: The text refers to a "European problem", which isn't further defined. Social taboos "exert power" over that problem (in some way which is also unspecified). As an independent free-thinker ("liberal intellect"), Murray isn't affected by the power of those taboos. For some unspecified reason, the writer thinks that given the above, we should *expect* Murray to be primitive and/or petty-minded, but in fact he is not (or at least, he doesn't *appear* to be).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Strange_Death_of_Europe

Answer (score 2):

The confusion here is probably the use of the verb 'to betray', which in this context is meaning 'to **reveal** or **expose**'.

Also 'atavism' is a very rare word indeed, basically meaning to show characteristics of an ancestor.

So the sentence could translate as: "He doesn't show the slightest hint of atavism or meanness." (mean-spiritedness <<< should have the dash like this.)